# Sharepoint Certification

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, certification

I have a 2 year intern experience background with SharePoint and now on a actual job also with SharePoint. My intern time was mostly with SP2013 and now my company uses SP 2010.

I want to make my knowledge official(not that big of a knowledge) so I am planning on taking some courses and certifications. Since I am on an Infrastructure area I got interested in the MCSE certification.

[MSCE Certification](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx)

The problem is that it is based on SharePoint 2013 and we have 2010 here.

No problem, eventually you will migrate - some could say. Yes, we will, but we are going to skip 2013 and go straight to 2016.

**Bottom line, my question is:**

Is the subject of the 2013 based course still valuable for a 2016 environment? Specially the infrastructure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I expect this question will quickly be flagged as opinion-based and be closed. But I'll give my input first.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 / 2016 certification is basically combination of office 365 & SharePoint or Windows Server & SharePoint, this is required to become MCSE.

Now there are difference in the SharePoint 2013 & 2016 course. In SharePoint 2013 we have streamline topology while in SharePoint 2016 we have MinRole. SharePoint 2016 is more towards cloud( hybrid approach).

in 2016 certification they asked for the scenarios so you have to study the 2016 course.

If you ask me, i would personally recommend you go for 2016 rather waste time & energy on 2013. It is always good experience, we learned alot during the training session about the basic of everything.

[Check this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think no. The individual exams aren't easy, let alone a full certification. The only time I would recommend certification is if you have aspirations to move into a more senior position at a new company. Even then, I've never needed my certifications. It looks good on a resume, but mine has expired and is not impeding my job search at all.

That being said, if you have aspirations to work for, say Microsoft or a renowned consulting firm, then you would want to get the 2013 anyway and I would say go for it.

Comment: The main reason to do this is to improve myself. I need more knowledge and the internet hasn't been enough. Of course I aspire for bigger roles in my company, but that will come with knowledge in practice rather than certifications.

Comment: I wouldn't say I learned anything from getting my certification. I would say I memorized a huge amount of information, a lot of which I never used again. I'm not saying don't do it. But maybe you could start with the books that are written to prep you for the exams. e.g. https://www.google.com/shopping/product/8110496668911517616?q=configuring+sharepoint+2010+certification

Comment: Btw, if your company will pay for classes and exams, that's obviously further incentive to do it. Make sure you take the exam somewhere that gives you a free second chance if you don't pass the first time.